# HTML Select Stays Open

Tags: javascript, select, dom-events, onchange, freeze

Got an HTML Select with an `onChange()` event that calls a method which takes about 5 seconds to complete.

In IE, the select remains open until the method has completed - just looks kind of tacky.  In Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, the Select appears to close without waiting for the method to complete.

I've also tried using the jQuery `change()` method and that doesn't help either.

Has anyone seen this before?  Recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a timeout and call your method after a small delay - that would give the drop-down enough time to close:

```
element.onchange = function() {
  setTimeout(method, 100);
};
```

The real question is why your method takes 5 seconds in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It indeed resolve the issue.  As to why my method takes 5 seconds, well, that's another story and not part of the issue.  Optimizations will come; this is an early release.